# eclipse jpa jql not generating on clause for one to many

Tags: sql, eclipse, jpa, join, jql

I have two tables:

DIDPool
DIDRange

A pool can have many ranges.

The range table doesn't have a parent id (e.g. no foreign key back to the pool) as the range table is used by a number of other entities.

As such I've setup the join so that it uses an intermediate join table tbldidpooldidrange.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbldidpool")
class DIDPool 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tbldidpooldidrange", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "did_pool_id")
          , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "did_range_id"))
    private ArrayList<DIDRange> didRanges = new ArrayList<DIDRange>();

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "tbldidrange")
public class DIDRange 
{@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    @AttributeOverride(name = "phoneNumber", column = @Column(name = "start"))
    private PhoneNumber start = new PhoneNumber();
}
```

The jpa correctly generates the intermediate join table.

My problem is in creating a jql expression that joins the two tables.

```
// Finds the pool that contains the given range or part range.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<DIDPool> findOverlapping(DIDRange didRange)
    {

        EntityManager em = EntityManagerProvider.getEntityManager();

        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM DIDPool e "
                + "join DIDRange r "
                + "where r.start.phoneNumber=:startNo"
                + " ) "
                );
        query.setParameter("startNo", didRange.getStartOfDIDRange().toCompactString());

        return (List<DIDPool>) query.getResultList();
    }
```

My understanding of jql is that you don't specify the join 'on' clause as jpa knows how to generate it.
However this is the sql the above clause generates:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
FROM tbldidrange t0, tbldidpool t1 WHERE t0.start = ?
    bind => [61383208100]
```

As you can see there is no 'on' clause (and the where doesn't join the tables) and the intermediate join table isn't even mentioned.

What am I doing wrong here?
I've been the reading the jpa documentation and its really not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM DIDPool e "
              + "join e.didRanges r "
              + "where r.start.phoneNumber=:startNo"
              + " ) "
               );
```

You have to use the ToMany attribute in the JOIN.